# How to change this codepen jQuery filter from <select> drop down to buttons?

Tags: jquery

I'm hacking away at [this Codepen jQuery filter](https://codepen.io/NickyCDK/pen/lhaiz) to suit my project and i'm hoping to replace the drop down with buttons. I'm sure it's pretty simple but I can't figure it out. My template (just a Bootstrap starter) already has CSS styling for buttons - just need to figure out what to do to the HTML and JS to get buttons instead of the drop down.

Code bits in question:

```js
//Filter News
$('select#sort-news').change(function() {
 var filter = $(this).val()
 filterList(filter);
});

//News filter function
function filterList(value) {
 var list = $(".news-list .news-item");
 $(list).fadeOut("fast");
 if (value == "All") {
  $(".news-list").find("article").each(function (i) {
   $(this).delay(200).slideDown("fast");
  });
 } else {
  //Notice this *=" <- This means that if the data-category contains multiple options, it will find them
  //Ex: data-category="Cat1, Cat2"
  $(".news-list").find("article[data-category*=" + value + "]").each(function (i) {
   $(this).delay(200).slideDown("fast");
  });
 }
}
```

```css
body {
 font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.news-item { display:inline-block; vertical-align:top; width:300px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Sort News</h2>
<select name="sort-news" id="sort-news">
 <option value="All">All news</option>
 <option value="Cat1">Category 1</option>
 <option value="Cat2">Category 2</option>
 <option value="Cat3">Category 3</option>
</select> 
<hr />
<section class="news-list">
  <article class="news-item" data-category="Cat1">
 <div class="thumb">
  <img alt="Our ALT text here" title="Our title here" src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
 </div>
 <div class="news-txt">
  <h3><a href="">A news title</a></h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua...</p>
 </div>
</article>
<article class="news-item" data-category="Cat2">
 <div class="thumb">
  <img alt="Our ALT text here" title="Our title here" src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
 </div>
 <div class="news-txt">
  <h3><a href="">A news title</a></h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua...</p>
 </div>
</article>
<article class="news-item" data-category="Cat3">
 <div class="thumb">
  <img alt="Our ALT text here" title="Our title here" src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
 </div>
 <div class="news-txt">
  <h3><a href="">A news title</a></h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua...</p>
 </div>
    </article>
  </section>
  <script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-12/jquery-2.0.3.min_1.js"></script>
```

Comment: Oh - and i'm obviously pretty uneducated on this stuff, so be gentle!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this:

```
<select name="sort-news" id="sort-news">
    <option value="All">All news</option>
    <option value="Cat1">Category 1</option>
    <option value="Cat2">Category 2</option>
    <option value="Cat3">Category 3</option>
</select>
```

with:

```
<button value="All">All news</button>
<button value="Cat1">Cat1</button>
<button value="Cat2">Cat2</button>
<button value="Cat3">Cat3</button>
```

and this:

```
$('select#sort-news').change(function(){...
```

with:

```
$('button').click(function() {...
```

Comment: Thank you!! THat works perfectly. I really really appreciate the help.